# Determining possible degree sequences.

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose G is a (10,23) graph and is also bipartite. Determine all possible degree sequences.
I can't seem to come up with a solution. There just seem to be too many possibilities. 
I know that if the graph is bipartite we need to come up with a partition of the vertices such that the sum of the degrees in each partition is 23. But then the issue arises such that G could be disconnected.

Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The key question is how many edges there are in the complete bipartite graph $K_{i, 10-i}$. Then subtract $23$ to see how many of those edges are missing.